# Add extra feature to a matrix np.Concatenate error : only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I want to add an extra column to my matrix in order to predict some features with some machine learning algorithms.

My trainSet got 8899 rows and 11 dimensions.

All i want to do is to add the extra dimension `distance` (see code).

But i got an error :

```
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

`temp_train_long/lat` is `(8899L,)`

```
X_train = df_train.as_matrix()
temp_train_long=(X_train[:,3] - X_train[:,7])**2#long
temp_train_lat = (X_train[:,4] - X_train[:,8])**2#lat
distance = np.sqrt(temp_train_long + temp_train_lat)
np.concatenate(X_train, distance.T)
```

Comment: Do not use Euclidean distance on long, lat. Earth is not flat.

Comment: thanks for the comment but it is not solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the `concatenate` docs

> concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0)

The function takes 2 arguments.  The first is a list or tuple, the arrays that you want to join.  The second is a number, denoting the axis.  And it returns a new array.  It does not operate in place.

```
X_train = df_train.as_matrix()
```

So this is 2d (8899, n), n larger than 9.  According to `pd` documentation this is a numpy `array` not a numpy `matrix` (that's important)

```
temp_train_long=(X_train[:,3] - X_train[:,7])**2#long
temp_train_lat = (X_train[:,4] - X_train[:,8])**2#lat
```

Two 1d arrays (8899,)

```
distance = np.sqrt(temp_train_long + temp_train_lat)
```

Also (8899,).   `distance.T` does nothing; that is not change in shape

```
np.concatenate(X_train, distance.T)
```

You give it 2 arguments, one is the 2d array, the other, in the `axis` slow is a 1d array.

You probably want

```
new_train = np.concatenate((X_train, distance[:,None]), axis=1)
```

2 array in one tuple, axis is scalar.  the `distance` array has been turned into a 2d 1 column array.